# Linear transformation and surjectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working through a question that I have been set. It starts of with the linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-x_2,x_1+x_2+x_3)$.

The first part asks you to prove it's not injective. I calculate the kernel of $T$ and that was nontrivial so that part's done. The second part I am however quite confused at. It asks you to prove that $T$ is surjective and has a hint that the answers should be short. Any answer I can think of would be quite long. Can anybody think of a short answer?

Comment: There's a famous formula involving the dimensions of the kernel and the image.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $T(1,0,0)=\dots$, $T(0,0,1)=\dots$, $T(1,1,-2)=\dots$

(It's indeed short.)

Comment: You don't need the last one. Surely a linear transformation has $0$ in its image. :)

Comment: @AymanHourieh But these three simple computations tell everything: first and second part.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: Or a sledgehammer. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Not really. This theorem is often useful when considering injectivity or surjectivity. Its proof doesn't require much theory. :)

Comment: Yes, I know well: it's my next week's topic. `;-)` In this case it's like a sledgehammer, though.